# iPhone required device capabilities - multi touch

Tags: iphone

My application requires multi touch, so I was checking the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html) and could't find the property to require multi touch. Do all versions of iOS devices support multi touch or I am missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to configure that. Every iOS device in existence (including the first-gen iPhone) supports multi-touch (unless its screen is defective). A pinch gesture, for example, is considered a multi-touch gesture, and is found in built-in apps like Maps and Mobile Safari.